# how to add custom event handler?

Tags: node.js, tcpsocket

can i add custom event handler in tcpsocket in 'net' core module in nodejs?
something like this

```
// Import net module.
var net = require('net');

// Create and return a net.Server object,
var server = net.createServer(function(client) {

    client.setEncoding('utf-8');
client.on('event1', function (data) {

console.log(data);
});
});
```

then emit this event by client 
if not can i use `on('data',callback);` and use data event to emit json string and handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for and emit events of any name on any event emitter. But unless you have some code which emits the event you are listening for, such as `server.emit('event1', data)`, the listener won't be called.